# Fail MariaDB-Access: ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - HikariPool-1 - dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required

Tags: spring, datasource, mybatis, hikaricp

While starting a new project, I'm blocked because I'm not able to access the database via Spring and myBatis. And I do not understand why.

- I've setup my application.properties (by copying from another of my
  projects).
- I've setup my MyBatis-@Configuration via java-class
  (DefaultDataAccessConfig.java)
- I've setup my Spring-context via xml-file (also almost same as
  before).
- I've setup my MainClass also very same as before.

When accessing via MainClass I get an error.

When accessing via my JUnit5-Test I'm fine.

All spring setup works fine, classes are instantiated and can be accessed. But when it comes to storing the data the program fails because of missing dataSource **and** missing dataSourceClassName **and** missing jdbcUrl (I debugged it, neither is there). The very same method failing when called via MainClass is called by my Test.
I have no clue, why myBatis is nother properly setup during start of MainClass.

I'm staring at the config and can't figure out whats wrong.
This is how it looks like:

**application.properties**

```
server.port = 8192
logging.level.root=WARN

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://DESKTOP-IOL7CPB.fritz.box:3306/smarthome?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=*******
spring.datasource.password=*******
spring.datasource.maximum-pool-size=30
# Number of ms to wait before throwing an exception if no connection is available.
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=60000
# Maximum number of active connections that can be allocated from this pool at the same time.
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
# Validate the connection before borrowing it from the pool.
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
```

**DefaultDataAccessConfig.java**

```
package de.gombers.smarthome.fritzbox.mybatis.configuration;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeHandler;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

@Configuration
@MapperScan({
    "de.gombers.smarthome.fritzbox.mybatis"})  
public class DefaultDataAccessConfig {

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory(@Autowired @Qualifier("myDataSource") DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("classpath*:mybatis/*-mapper.xml");
        sessionFactory.setMapperLocations(resources);
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        TypeHandler[] typeHandlers = { new CustomDateTypeHandler() };
        sessionFactory.setTypeHandlers(typeHandlers);
        return sessionFactory.getObject();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public HikariDataSource myDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }
    
    
    @Bean 
    public SqlSession sqlSession(@Autowired SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) {
        return sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
        
    }
}
```

**/context/smartHome.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- enable autowire -->
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="de.gombers.smarthome" />
</beans>
```

**Main class**

```
@Service
public class GatherStatisticsMain {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GatherStatisticsMain.class);

    private final static String contextxml="/context/smartHome.xml";
    
    @Autowired
    private HomeAutomation homeAutomation;
    
    @Autowired
    private StoreDevices storeDevices;

    public GatherStatisticsMain() {
    }

    public void process() throws InterruptedException {
        final DeviceList devices = homeAutomation.getDeviceListInfos();
        storeDevices.process(devices);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(contextxml);
        LOGGER.info("------------" + context.getBeanDefinitionCount());

        GatherStatisticsMain main = (GatherStatisticsMain) context.getBean(GatherStatisticsMain.class);
        main.process();
    }
```

**JUnit5-Test**

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:context/smartHome.xml")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DevicesDAOTest {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Tools.getSimpleClassName());
    @Autowired
    private DevicesDAO devicesDAO;
    @Autowired
    private DeviceBuilder devicesBuilder;
    
    
    @Test
    @DisplayName("Add new device")
    public void addDeviceTest() throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
        DeviceType device = devicesBuilder
                .init()
                .setIdentifier("Identifier")
                .setManufacturer("Manufact")
                .setName("Name")
                .setProductname("ProductName")
                .build();
        try {
            Optional<DeviceType> oDevice = devicesDAO.getDeviceByIdentifier(device.getIdentifier());
            devicesDAO.deleteDeviceByIdentifier(device.getIdentifier());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.info("No previous occurence of device '{}' to be deleted", device.getIdentifier());
        }
        devicesDAO.insertDevice(device);
        Long count = devicesDAO.getTotalRows();
        Long result = 1L;
        assertEquals("Size ok", result, count);
    }
}
```

An the error I see is:

```
10:06:57.159 [main] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Creating a new SqlSession
10:06:57.159 [main] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@7bebcd65] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
10:06:57.163 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
10:06:57.164 [main] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - HikariPool-1 - dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
10:06:57.164 [main] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@7bebcd65]
Exception in thread "main" org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
### The error may exist in file [E:\$SysProg\GIT\SmallTools\SmartHome\target\classes\mybatis\Devices-mapper.xml]
### The error may involve de.gombers.smarthome.fritzbox.mybatis.objects.DevicesMapper.getDeviceByIdentifier
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:79)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:447)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.selectOne(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:167)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:82)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.getDeviceByIdentifier(Unknown Source)
    at de.gombers.smarthome.fritzbox.mybatis.objects.DevicesDAO.getDeviceByIdentifier(DevicesDAO.java:35)
    at de.gombers.smarthome.fritzbox.mybatis.serializer.StoreDevices.isAlreadyPersisted(StoreDevices.java:56)
    at de.gombers.smarthome.fritzbox.mybatis.serializer.StoreDevices.storeDevice(StoreDevices.java:44)
    at de.gombers.smarthome.fritzbox.mybatis.serializer.StoreDevices.process(StoreDevices.java:39)
    at de.gombers.smarthome.fritzbox.main.GatherStatisticsMain.process(GatherStatisticsMain.java:62)
    at de.gombers.smarthome.fritzbox.main.GatherStatisticsMain.main(GatherStatisticsMain.java:78)
```

Comment: You are using Spring Boot but aren't... Ditch your datasource bean definition, change your `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` to `SpringBootApplication.run(GatherStatisticsMain, args);` and restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to M. Deinum, who put me on the right track. I was not aware of mybatis-spring-boot-starter. As I had said, I had ***also*** tried to start the Main-class with @SpringBootApplication - and this had failed with the same error. Now I learned, that it failed, because the "DefaultDataAccessConfig.class". Right now I also can toggle between failing, just by introducing this class. The beans instantiated by this class seem to disturb in a way the correct setup.

Its all kind of magic. I removed

- /context/smartHome.xml
- DefaultDataAccessConfig.java

and ran the MainClass as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Spring Boot but are also trying very hard not to.

1. Ditch your xml configuration
2. Ditch your `DataSource` bean
3. Use `@SpringBootApplication` on `GatherStatisticsMain` instead of `@Service`
4. Fix your `main` to use `SpringApplication.run` instead of `new ApplicationContext`.

```java
@Configuration
@MapperScan({
    "de.gombers.smarthome.fritzbox.mybatis"})  
public class DefaultDataAccessConfig {

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("classpath*:mybatis/*-mapper.xml");
        sessionFactory.setMapperLocations(resources);
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        TypeHandler[] typeHandlers = { new CustomDateTypeHandler() };
        sessionFactory.setTypeHandlers(typeHandlers);
        return sessionFactory.getObject();
    }
 
    @Bean 
    public SqlSession sqlSession(SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) {
        return sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
        
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** When using the MyBatis Spring Boot starter I think you can even ditch this configuration class.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatherStatisticsMain {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GatherStatisticsMain.class);

    private final static String contextxml="/context/smartHome.xml";
    
    @Autowired
    private HomeAutomation homeAutomation;
    
    @Autowired
    private StoreDevices storeDevices;

    public void process() throws InterruptedException {
        final DeviceList devices = homeAutomation.getDeviceListInfos();
        storeDevices.process(devices);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringBootApplication.run(GatherStatisticsMain.class, args);         LOGGER.info("------------" + context.getBeanDefinitionCount());

        GatherStatisticsMain main context.getBean(GatherStatisticsMain.class);
        main.process();
    }
}
```

Your test class should now look something like this.

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class DevicesDAOTest { ... }
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand how this is going to work:
(1) If I delete the xml, spring will not scan packages for beans. I could introduce this by annotation, but what's the difference.
(2) Deleting Datasource will not help. I currently fail because I don't have one. The Unit-Test even works fine with this definiton. And fails with your suggestion. And Main doesn't work either.
(3) Running with\@ SpringBootApplication instead of  \@Service does not make a difference. 
(4) The Unit-tests looks already as you suggest. But it also needs the Datasource, as already mentioned above.

Comment: Did some reading about mybatis-spring-boot and learned, at least, that this can help to automate a lot of work about setup under the hood. So you are probably right, though I still don't understand it yet. It seems it is going to become hard work to get this known.
At least, thank you so far.

Comment: 1. Spring Boot does that by default. 2. Yes it will if you specify the correct properties `spring.datasource.url` for instance. 3. than you haven't done as told. 4. No it doesn't you have a a load more annotations.